# Fill HTML table with stored procedure SELECT statement output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using C# .NET MVC 4 and entity framework to execute a stored procedure. I have a query that is running in the stored procedure that looks something like:

```
Select Column1, Column2, Column3
from TestTable
Where StatusId = 3;
```

So lets say this returns about 50 rows. I am trying to get the output from the `SELECT` statement into an HTML table in my View. I haven't done this type of thing before so I am not sure of the best approach. Could that much data be sent back to the controller in output parameters. If so, I don't quite understand the approach to format that data into the `HTML` table.

I've done something similar before, but in that case I only had one row come back each time so I just sent the data back to the controller in output parameters and then sent it to my view in a `ViewBag`. What is the best approach with multiple rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in your edmx, your stored procedure will have generated a complex type (which is essentially a data structure of a row of your result set)

when you call your sproc, either pass the result set (tolist()) of your complex type directly to the view or make a viewmodel version of your sproc's complex type and pass that instead.

then in your view, you just need to make a table and foreach item in the model, make a  and populate the data cells accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
ICollection<Object> data = your stored procedure result here...
ViewBage.data = data;
```

In your page

```
foreach (var rowin ViewBag.data)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@row.Fieldx</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a entity in your model that mapping your table attribute. 
   ex:

   MyTableMapping{
    int col1{get; set;}
    string col2{ get; set;}
    ....
   }
2. In your controller execute a stored procedure and cast your result in a collection of yout Model mapping created before.
   When you call a view pass it a collection

   public ActionResult Index(){
      [your code to load data from Database]
   ...
      return View(yourCollection);
   }
3. In your view cshtml file setting a type model same of `IEnumerable<ModelMapping>`
   then use a Web grid for MVC 4.
   here an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

The Stored Procedure will be called by passing the parameter value using Entity Framework.

Once the Entity Framework is configured, the next step is to import the Stored Procedure in the Entity Framework model. In order to do so, you will need to Right Click the Entity Model and select Update Model from Database option.

The Stored Procedure is called in the Controller and Entity is returned to the View.
Very well explained [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Call-Stored-Procedure-using-Entity-Framework.aspx)